# Possible to send email on table refresh using SQL Server or SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, email, ssis, ssms

I am curious if it is possible using SSMS or SSIS to have an automated email sent out when a table refreshes each day?  We have a table that logs the last refresh of a series of tables - which ideally occurs once per day.  The idea is that folks won't use/trust the data in that table if they aren't sure its refreshed (it feeds from an ERP that is live).  Sorry for being vague but I couldn't find answers that seemed to solve the issue. Right now there is a some website that very few are aware of, just curious if Microsoft has a solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/846204/how-to-send-mail-using-sql-server-part

After the table refresh execute EXEC sp_send_dbmail

Comment: Any thoughts or feedback about the answer I provided? Have you had a chance to try it?

Comment: Hey, thank you for that. I think that may end up being the best option but my admin will have to set that up.  It helps knowing what to ask for though so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have a SQL Agent job or a SSIS package send an email. If you choose SSIS, you are going to use the Send Mail Task. In the control flow, put the Send Mail Task after your data flow task (or whatever your last step is). You must create a SMTP Connection Manager, which is your email server. When doing this, you may merely need to put in the name of the server, e.g. mail.mydomain.com, or you may check a box or two depending on your email server.

[image: SMTP Connection Manager]

When configuring your Send Mail Task, choose the SMPT Connection manager you just created. Put in a From address, To address, Subject, Message Source, etc. You can simply type in the values you want.

[image: Send Mail Task]

If you want to get a little fancy, you can create expressions for some of these values. For example, if you want the email body to include some details about the load such as completion time or row counts, you can easily do that. One way is to use expressions to populate the message body, subject, etc. Here is an expression that I use in a package when it encounters an error:

```
"Package start time: " + (DT_WSTR, 50) @[System::StartTime] +"\r\nEvent handler start time: " + (DT_WSTR, 50) @[System::EventHandlerStartTime] + "\r\nPackage running on: " + @[System::MachineName] + "\r\nPackage started by: " +  @[System::UserName] + "\r\nError code: "+ @[System::ErrorDescription] + "\r\nError description: " +  @[System::ErrorDescription]
```

It includes details such as the name of the package, the machine it's running on (to easily discern what environment experienced the error (Dev/QA/UAT/Prod).

[image: Send Mail Task Expressions]